# jQuery focus on clicked content

Tags: jquery

I have `article` elements which have inner html which are `.article-row` and `.content.`

`.content` is hidden and when `.article-row` is clicked `.content` will then show. But I would like the other `article`'s to `.hide()` so that the `.content` of the currently clicked item is the only item in view.

```
$('.article-row').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).parent().find('.content').is(':visible')){
        $('.content').hide();
    }else{
        $('.content').hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.content').show();
    }
});

$('.close').click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().hide();    
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Beardyco/QpA6b/)

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't it work already?

Comment: Your code is doing it currently, what's the problem ?

Comment: The only thing I'll add is it can be simplified as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/bqzvt/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use not function in jquery for this. I have updated your fiddle like this. Please check out.

```
$('.article-row').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('.article-row').not(this).hide();
if($(this).parent().find('.content').is(':visible')){
    $('.content').hide();
}else{
    $('.content').hide();
    $(this).parent().find('.content').show();
}
 });

 $('.close').click(function(e){
  $('.article-row').show();
  $(this).parent().hide();    
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QpA6b/2/

Comment: @PatsyIssa my code works but I needed the extra addition of hiding `.article-rows`